# pyautogui glitches when I try finding a pixel color, but it also works sometimes when I don't even change the code

Tags: python

Simple piano tiles bot I made, it used to work but it stopped working recently, when I run it, I receive an error, but a few times I ran the exact same thing it works perfectly.

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.05)  
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)


while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    if pyautogui.pixel(480, 280)[0] == 0:
        click(480, 280)
    if pyautogui.pixel(550, 280)[0] == 0:
        click(550, 280)
    if pyautogui.pixel(620, 280)[0] == 0:
        click(620, 280)
    if pyautogui.pixel(688, 280)[0] == 0:
        click(688, 280)
```

The error that pops up when I try running it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sijav\PycharmProjects\Piano Tiles Bot\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    if pyautogui.pixel(550, 280)[0] == 0:
  File "C:\Users\sijav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 613, in pixel
    return (r, g, b)
  File "C:\Users\sijav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 124, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\sijav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 122, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0

Process finished with exit code 1
:
```

Comment: What's the error? You only list the traceback (a.k.a. stack trace).

Comment: added the entire error